# copy paste in markup poor perforamnce vs 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Im using cs 2010 ultimate. Every time I try to paste any markup into my ascx file VS frozes for 5-10 s.  The same situation is for example when im typing CssClass=" ...

At thios moment vs frozes.

Can I make it work faster?

Thanks for any hints

EDIT: Please help me to improve my vs performance. editing ascx file is very slow.

Comment: "bye"? You don't just post a question here then run off.

Comment: thanks for helpfull answer, now bye if you dont have anything to say

Answer (score 2):

Do you have installed the "productivity power tools" addin ? 
I had the same problem while pasting data to ascx files, solved it by going to Option -> Productivity Power Tools , then desactivate "HTML Copy".

Comment: Did help some, but isn't like it should be though!

Answer (score 0):

doownload this patch, it may solve your problem. [Cut or Copy displays 'insufficient memory' error in Visual Studio 2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29729)